# How to give custom color to selected map feature using PointSelection command in MapXtreme SDK

Tags: mapinfo, asp.net, mapxtreme

I am developing a GIS web application in Asp.Net using MapXtreme(V8.0)SDK. I have a requirement of highlighting selected feature with cursor. I am able to do that with below code

```
<cc1:PointSelectionTool ID="PointSelectionTool1" runat="server" MapControlID="MapControl1" ClientCommand="PointSelectionCommand" Command="PointSelection" />
```

But, by default it is giving red color to selected features.

Is there is anyway to change this color?

Answer (score 1):

The Mapping.FeatureViewer.DrawSelections property controls whether selections should get drawn.

I'm guess there is a property that can control the style these selections are drawn with as well.

Unfortunately I don't have MapXtreme installed at the moment and therefor I don't have access to the full object model.